# How to Implement Site Map in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Can any one Guide me I ma newer how we Implement site Map in Asp.net MVC website
Thanks in advance

Comment: You  can use [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider)

Answer (score 1):

Use can use `System.Xml.Linq`

```
public ContentResult GetSiteMap()
{
    XNamespace ns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
    XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    return new XElement(ns + "urlset",
        new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
        new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"),
        from node in db.MyTable()
        select new XElement(ns + "url",
            new XElement(ns + "loc", node.Loc),
            new XElement(ns + "lastmod", node.LastMod),
            new XElement(ns + "priority", node.Priority)
        )
    ).ToString();
    return Content(xsi.ToString(), "text/xml"); 
}
```

Comment: Dear it will give error at from node in db.MyTable() like you can use table as a method. can you told me. plz

Comment: Thanks Got Point....

Comment: you need to change db.MyTable() with the connection to you table (using Linq)